# Getting USER_PERMISSION_DENIED in google ads api when trying to fetch client info of which allowed access in authentication

Tags: google-ads-api

I am trying to fetch client account info using MCC ad account. I prompted user for authentication to my app. After successful authentication, I used the client id and token to fetch the detail.

[image]

Comment: did you solve it?